# how to charge marine battery at my wall

Tags: electrical, solar-panels, battery

i have all kinds of batteries in my house.  when my xbox controller is out of battery, i charge it from my wall.  when my phone is out of battery, i also plug it into the wall.  i'd like to get a whole bunch of marine batteries.  how do i charge them from my wall?

thanks

Comment: XY problem. Better to state what you are trying to actually do.

Comment: Please explain your goals. As the top answer indicates, you can get a 12v battery charger at many places. Does that actually accomplish your goal? Probably not unless the goal is to have marine batteries sitting around fully charged doing nothing.

Comment: ahhh... stack overflow in all its glory.  i've missed you guys.

Answer (score 6):

12 volt battery charger, sold in any place that sells batteries.

Answer (score 1):

A multi circuit battery tender would do the job.   But again, what are you trying to accomplish? to moderators:  I wanted to post this as a comment, but can't bc you can't post pics in a comment. sorry.

[image: battery charger]

Comment: You can to [post images in a comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrQMa.png) (via a link).

Comment: @FreeMan  I thought links were discouraged here because they can change often.

Comment: It's just a comment that can be deleted by a mod any time...